Where did Bruce Almighty get "Insta" from?
In Bruce Almighty, Jim Carrey (as God) receives prayers using a website he just made called Yahweh Insta-Prayer:

Although close to Instagram it seemed too early to be a parody of it, and Googling it confirmed that Instagram was only found in 2010 and is itself is a portmanteu of "instant camera" and "telegram". Was Insta-Prayer a parody of anything that existed at the time, or were the writers just going for something as simple as "instant prayer"? Has this ever been addressed by the producers or any BTS footage?

Yahoo. Insta is simply from "instant".

@Mithoron - Yahoo's messaging product was called "Yahoo Messenger", no Instant.

Instagram is not the first Insta- brand - for example, Kodak Instamatic from 1963

Why is this question being downvoted?

Bruce has designed a website that features a range of fairly obviously references to two popular Internet services of the time, Yahoo! and AOL.
Yahoo! references.

Yahweh! is a fairly obvious play on Yahoo!, even down to the logo with slightly wonky lettering





The obnoxious jingle is nearly identical.







The email interface is similar to Yahoo! Mail of the period.




AOL

"You've got prayers" is a fairly obvious play on "you've got mail"

The key functionality of Bruce's website is a tool called Insta-Prayer, aping the name of AOL's Instant Messenger.






Obviously Bruce chose to call his own service something slightly different for his own personal reasons.

Crazy that the Yahoo connection didn't occur to me, I just assumed it was a direct reference to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahweh.

@Prometheus - ON reflection, I think Insta- is from AOL Instant Messenger. Yahoo Messenger didn't have the word "instant" in the title, afaik

@Prometheus They used the similarity to comedic effect.
